# Prove that $a_n = f(\frac{1}{n})$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : (0,1] → \mathbb{R}$ is diﬀerentiable, and $|f'(x)|≤ 1$ for all $x \in (0,1]$. Prove that $a_n = f(1/n)$ converges.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Cauchy sequence / criterion and mean value theorem

Comment: Hint: $|f'(x)| \le 1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in (0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: show it's a Cauchy sequence, by applying the Mean Value Theorem
to estimate $|f(1/n) - f(1/m)|$.

Comment: Could you construct a counterexample if the assumption $|f^\prime(x)|\leq 1$ is violated?

Comment: Obviously $|f'(x)| \le C$ for any constant $C$ is just as good.  If $f'$ is not bounded, try $f(x) = \cos(\pi/x)$ .